# PHP upload speeds very spikey/slow

Tags: php, performance, file-upload, centos

I originally posted this over in the Drupal exchange but it was suggested I try here since it seems to be more related to my server, not Drupal.

When uploading files through php, the upload speed can see drastic slow downs. For example, I'm uploading a 400MB video and I'll be getting 10mbps then, suddenly, it drops to less than 100kbps. After some time, it speeds up again. Then it slows down again. And then repeats. There is no consistency as to when this happens. I can get this to replicate with large files and small files but since it is erratic, it's harder to observe on small files. I have not observed this uploading through SCP, so I assume it's not a network issue.

Here is what I know.

1. It's not my internet connection. I've tried multiple people from different places with the same results.
2. Tried on several browsers with the same result.
3. Eventually the upload will complete but in a lot of instances, an upload that should take 4 minutes ends up taking 30 or more.
4. PHP is set to allow 2GB file uploads. And PECL uploadprogress is installed.
5. Though I use Drupal, I've also tried uploading files through a straight-forward php upload form with the same results. So it's not a Drupal issue.

What I think is happening - at some point during the upload process, some sort of buffer is being hit. I really don't even know where to begin looking for that at the server or OS-level

We have plenty of disk space (more than 1TB) and plenty of RAM (24GB)

I'm hoping someone here has experienced similar or can suggest where to begin looking. Thanks for reading!

Comment: its an issue with your host

Comment: Hi Dagon, I'm not going to disagree with you that it isn't an issue with my host but do you have a suggestion I can approach them with or something I can test? Like I said, I'd consider it's an issue with their network only I don't seem to have an issue with SCP transfers.

Comment: they are far more likely to shape http traffic than scp

Comment: Interesting possibility that I hadn't considered. We're not on a low-end host but I will file a ticket to see how they respond.